# Have errors when running in my real device makeng app from android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, runtime-error

I'm makeng .apk files in android studio 1.3.2. When running on my real device have a errors  in device (lenovoA526) and othets phone.  I install all the drivers.
Showing errors to logcat:

```
16807/com.example.behzod.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXECEPTION: Main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.example.behzod.myapplication/com.example.behzod.myapplication.MainActivity}: 
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:  
File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020052
```

How can i remove this errors?

Comment: check that if there is "abc_vector_test.xml" file present in drawable folder or not

Comment: It's not present. I can't see.

Comment: check where are you using that and add that file

Comment: I'm beginer i can't find this file

Comment: post your MainActivity's layout file

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ManActivity">
```